# REGEX pregmatch for username

Tags: php, regex

Does anyone know why in this regular expresion:

$name ="abcdefABCDF12345àáâäãåèéêëìíîïòóôöõøùúûüÿ ýñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅ∂ð"$[]%&/()^*?¿¨_-{}:;,.Ç"

```
 if(!preg_match("[a-zA-Z0-9àáâäãåèéêëìíîïòóôöõøùúûüÿýñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŸÝÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð &\.\'-_]+", $name))
{
//is also matching []/()^*?:;,
}
```

in any case how should I set to allow &.'-_ (yes, dot and & too but not the above mentioned).

Thanks.

Comment: You are missing delimeters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'-_` means all characters between `'` and `_`.
You need to escape the `-`.  (incidentally, you don't need to escape anything else)

Comment: The `-` doesn't need to be escaped if it's the final thing inside of the character class. `[A-Z-]` will match all of `A` through `Z` plus `-`.

Comment: @j883376: Yes, but here, it isn't.

Comment: @Miguel: You already knew that.  What did you think `a-z` means?

Comment: @SLaks true , that happen when you're not used to have it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the "-". Also, you need to add delimeters in the beggining and in the end.